# Reading in data with different delimiters in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read in the following data from a file using Python 2.7:
3

```
0.32,0.32,0.12,0.04,0.07,0.13
3,7
32,62 42,68 12,98
95,13 97,25 93,37 79,27 75,19 49,47 67,17
```

The values are mostly comma separated but in the second to last line sets of data points are space delimited. Any ideas on how I can read in this data from a csv file?

Comment: Use a regex split by either spaces or commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex split by either spaces or commas.

```
with open('data.csv') as data:
    lines = [re.split(r'\s+|,', i.strip()) for i in data]
```

Answer (score 4):

[As per the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402867/reading-in-data-with-different-delimiters-in-python/29402968#comment46981166_29402867), just split each line according to the  comma or a space through `re.split` function.

```
import re
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.split(r'[,\s]', line.strip()))
```

`[,\s]` character class which matches either a comma or a `\s` space character.

**Output:**

```
['0.32', '0.32', '0.12', '0.04', '0.07', '0.13']
['3', '7']
['32', '62', '42', '68', '12', '98']
['95', '13', '97', '25', '93', '37', '79', '27', '75', '19', '49', '47', '67', '17']
```

Comment: Same time? Must have been thinking the same thing.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi not same time. Posted the answer after seeing your comment.

Comment: Our answer are actually a bit different. I used an regex or and you used a class (;

Comment: @Priya Welcome to StackOverflow.Accept an answer which you love the most.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, if there is only one space between fields, would be to replace each space with a comma, or each comma with a space, then use split () as appropriate. If the restriction does not hold, you will need a regex that handles it appropriately.

"*Whenever you choose regex as a solution to your problem, you have two problems.*"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say precisely what format you wanted the sets of data points read in as, but if the data points together represent a "value", you could do something like this:

```
with open('sample_data.csv') as csvfile:
    for line in (line.strip() for line in csvfile):
        row = line.split(sep=None if ' ' in line else ',')
        print(row)
```

The `str.split()` method accepts an optional keyword argument that tells it what delimiter string to split upon, however if it's not given or is given and set to `None`, it then considers consecutive whitespace the delimiters. The code above checks to see if each line has any space characters in it and passes the appropriate keyword argument value to `split()` depending on what kind of data appears to be in that line.

Output:

```
['0.32', '0.32', '0.12', '0.04', '0.07', '0.13']
['3', '7']
['32,62', '42,68', '12,98']
['95,13', '97,25', '93,37', '79,27', '75,19', '49,47', '67,17']
```